# How to reuse @Autowired bean in super class?

Tags: java, spring, oop, autowired

My curent project is having two services:

```
@Service
public class OtherService{
}

interface IService{
    void methodA();
    void methodB();
    void methodC();
}

@Service
public class DefaultService implement IService{

    @Autowried
    private OtherService otherService;

    public void methodA(){...};
    public void methodB(){...};
    public void methodC(){...};
}
```

When implement other feature, i have added new business flow:

- want to reuse methodA, methodB
- add new rule when running methodC in new flow

So my solution is creating `new ChildService extends DefaultService` and overwrite `methodC`.

```
@Service
public class ChildService extends DefaultService{

    @override               
    public void methodC(){
        //want to use some method of otherService
    }
}
```

The problem is `methodC` want to use `otherService` bean in parent class. I am having two solutions:

1. change `private OtherService otherService` to `protected OtherService otherService`. But thinking `protected` with `@Autowired` bean is not good practice?
2. add `@Autowried private OtherService otherService;` into `ChildService`

What is better or any suggestion for this case?

Comment: both seems fine to me. I'd go with 2 but it's just a matter of opinion

Comment: add a public / protected getter for `OtherService`

Comment: I highly discourage soultion 1. since attribute hiding makes it hard to read the code. Actually, I would write a getter for the attribute and inject the attribute in the constructor rather than injecting the attribute itself (everytime you autowire an attribute, a Unit test dies...).

Comment: i minimized the code, `DefaultService` injected more than 3 services, so i don't want to use inject constructor. btw, how `getter` for `OtherService `is better than protected attribute ?

Comment: While making the `otherService` field `protected` will work, using class inheritance in order to "reuse methodA, methodB" is a highly questionable design decision. Even more so as the base class `DefaultService` is an interface implementation (possible interface overuse?). The common advice in cases like this is to "favor composition over inheritance". Although I suspect that `IService` is "too big", lacking cohesion.

Answer (score 1):

Edited.

Change the access specifier of OtherService to protected or provide a 
protected getOtherService() method in DefaultService.